# How can I get TOP in a GROUP BY?

Tags: sql-server

```
OrderUTC                Symbol  TargetPosition  
2011-02-01 3:59:59.000  GBPUSD  1000000 
2011-02-01 13:59:59.000 GBPUSD  1000000 
2011-02-01 5:59:59.000  EURUSD  1000000 
2011-02-01 22:59:59.000 EURUSD  1000000
```

I want to get the LAST TargetPosition by Symbol - how can I do this?

```
  SELECT TOP(1)  [Symbol],[TargetPosition]
  FROM [FX].[dbo].[Orders] 
  GROUP BY [Symbol]
  ORDER BY [OrderUTC]
```

Does NOT work

> Column 'FX.dbo.Orders.TargetPosition' is invalid in the select list
>   because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>   GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is using row_number and then taking just the number 1s, like this:

```
select Symbol,TargetPosition from (
  SELECT Symbol,TargetPosition,
    row_number() over (partition by Symbol order by OrderUTC) as RN
  FROM [FX].[dbo].[Orders]
) X
where RN = 1
```

Comment: I would think the order by would be desc. to get the "last" assuming most current.

Comment: Wow - does it really need to be this complicated for a simple query?

Comment: @xQbert Yes it might need desc in the order by, but the OPs SQL was also missing it.

Comment: @ManInMoon If you have data in one table this is normally the best way to do it. If you have symbols in one table and positions in another, you could do it with outer apply + top 1

Comment: @maininMoon believe it or not, this is the simple way.  Alternative methods involve subqueries to identify max dates and then joins back to base sets.

Answer (score 1):

Use a windowing function instead to order each symbol's pricing independently.

```
select * from
    (select symbol, targetposition
        , row_number() over (partition by symbol order by orderutc desc) as rn
from fx.dbo.orders) as A where a.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems right off the bat.  First, TOP limits the number of records returned, it does not care about the values. Second GROUP implies an aggregate function will be applied to all non-grouped columns that are used (TargetPosition and OrderUTC).

Now, to do what you want to do, there are already a few answers that will work, so I will give you something slightly different.

```
SELECT
  Symbol,
  FIRST_VALUE(TargetPosition) OVER (PARTITION BY Symbol ORDER BY OrderUTC DESC)
FROM
  FX.dbo.Orders
GROUP BY
  Symbol
```

Comment: @ManInMoon, does FIRST_VALUE throw an error?  If I am reading this correctly (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018.aspx) it looks like it applies to SQL Server 2012 and up, are you using 2008? In SQL Server Management Studio FIRST_VALUE is not colored pink like other windowed functions but it does work.

Comment: YEs 2008 - it does not recognise it

Comment: @ManInMoon, thats bad luck.  It looks like you probably need to go with what one of the others suggested.  Sorry I can't be more help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the number of distinct symbols compared to the total number of rows is very small. Instead of using an aggregation, I would use APPLY for that. This will do just one seek for each Symbol.

I would create a table which contains all possible symbols (GBPUSD, EURUSD...). Let's call it SymbolTable and try this:

```
WITH Symbols AS
(
  SELECT Symbol
  FROM SymbolTable
)
SELECT S.Symbol, A1.TargetPosition
FROM Symbols AS S
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP (1) O.TargetPosition
             FROM [FX].[dbo].[Orders] AS O
             WHERE O.Symbol = S.Symbol
             ORDER BY OrderUTC DESC
            ) AS A1;
```

But you need an index for that (Symbol ASC, OrderUTC DESC, INCLUDE TargetPosition).  If there are many distinct symbols, using a window-function will perform better than this solution.

Answer (score 0):

using `Over Partition by symbol` is a better solution.  However, for someone not familiar with analytic functions, this may be easier to understand.

Before analytics, before CTEs, this was a common approach to achieve the desired results.

Get a set of data consisting of max date for each symbol then join the results back to a base set to eliminate the non-current symbols and get the target position having the max date.

So  using set based processing we have a set of symbols and their max dates we join that set back to the entire set to eliminate those symbols not having max dates leaving the symbol and targetPosition of the max date.

```
SELECT A.Symbol, A.TargetPosition
FROM ORDERS A
INNER JOIN (SELECT max(OrderUTC) mDate, symbol 
  FROM orders
  GROUP BY Symbol) B
 on B.mDate = A.orderUTC
and B.Symbol = A.Symbol
```